# Парсинг сайта myip.ms

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Пишу парсер для сайта https://myip.ms/
И вот для этой страницы https://myip.ms/browse/sites/1/ipID/23.227.38.0/ipIDii/23.227.38.255/own/376714
С этой ссылкой всё работает отлично, но если перейти на другую страницу https://myip.ms/browse/sites/2/ipID/23.227.38.0/ipIDii/23.227.38.255/own/376714
То никаких данных не выводит, хотя структура сайта такая же. Я думаю что это может быть связанно с тем что на сайте стоит лимит на просмотры, или из-за того что надо зарегистрироваться, но я не могу найти какой запрос надо отправить для входа в аккаунт.
Подскажите что сделать?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
link_list = []

URL = 'https://myip.ms/browse/sites/2/ipID/23.227.38.0/ipIDii/23.227.38.255/own/376714'

HEADERS = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 YaBrowser/20.12.2.105 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36','accept':'*/*'}
#HOST =
def get_html(url,params=None):
    r = requests.get(url,headers=HEADERS,params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('td',class_='row_name')
    for item in items:
        links = item.find('a').get('href')
        link_list.append({
            'link': links
        })

def parser():
    print(URL)

    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Error')

parser()
print(link_list)
```

Comment: а не проще выкачать базу данных регистратора?

Comment: @eri а можно подробнее пожалуйста ?